# When I try persist entity in doctrine2 a get message 'Undefined method 'persist'

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

When I try persist entity in doctrine2 (zf2) for example:

```
 $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Application\Entity\Publications');

  $oPublications = new \Application\Entity\Publications();
      $oPublications->setContent("some text");
      $repository->persist($oPublications);
      $repository->flush();
```

I still get above error:

Undefined method 'persist'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

What I doing wrong?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

`persist` and `flush` are methods of the EntityManager.
This should work:

```
$oPublications = new \Application\Entity\Publications();
$oPublications->setContent("some text");
$this->getEntityManager()->persist($oPublications);
$this->getEntityManager()->flush();
```